# Accessing Google Drive : Operation not supported

Tags: bash

I am trying to create an alias on a google drive location to another. When I run it via a terminal command I get Operation not supported. 
Whats wrong, as I am able to create an alias quite well outside Google Drive Volume?

```
ln -s "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Links/Brush Creek/2020 Brush Creek - qq" "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Shared drives/Media Projects/Brush Creek/Projects/2020/2020 Brush Creek - qqq"
```

Comment: Google drive probably doesn't support symlinks.